# How to run Selenium Webdriver C# tests on multiple remote machines in parallel?

Tags: c#, nunit, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I'm currently using Selenium Webdriver and developing my tests in Visual Studio 2012 with C#. I've successfully executed a remote test by using the following code:

```
public static void Test_RemoteWebDriver()
       {
        string url = "http://11.11.11.11:4444/wd/hub";

        DesiredCapabilities ieCapibility = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
        ieCapibility.SetCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(url), ieCapibility);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");           
        driver.Quit();
       }
```

What I want to do now is to use one machine as the automation controller and execute the tests on multiple remote machines. To clarify, I want to have the Selenium code on my controller machine but be able to run the test on multiple remote machines. How do I do this?
I'm also using NUnit to run my tests but I understand this may not be the best solution for parallel testing. What would be the best framework to run remote Selenium tests?
Many Thanks for any help,
John

Comment: You understand what you're trying accomplish is a huge dev task, it's nothing you'll get by implementing some simple functionality offered by a library.

Comment: I've clarified my question, I apologise if I was vague. I'm sure this has been done before using something like Grid but I was hoping the experts might tell me what the best way to do this is.

Comment: At my previous job our automation was capable of this but the code that did it was a custom made scheduler which was responsible for kicking off all kinds of tasks. I don't think there is any simple way to achieve this functionality, I could be wrong but in general it's not a simple problem, I don't think you'll find a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while so here's what I ended up doing. I ended up using NUnit to run the tests. Now my automation copies both NUnit and Selenium files to the remote machine, runs the automation there and copies the results file back to the controller machine. Works well for my needs.
John

Answer (score 0):

What I've done, I'm not sure if this is the best approach, is adding an entry for each server I want to test in the app.config, within the appsettings section, as follows:

```
 <!-- Server URLs to test  -->    
<add key="ApplicationUrl_DEV" value="http://localhost:44404"/>
<add key="ApplicationUrl_TEST" value="http://testserver:44404"/>
```

And then in the test class, I add the attributes as:

```
[TestFixture("ApplicationUrl_DEV", "DEV")]
[TestFixture("ApplicationUrl_TEST", "TEST")]
public abstract class Executer // Test class
```

Each test method in the class will execute N times, once for each ´TestFixture´ attribute.
After this, you must overload the class constructor:

```
protected Executer(string urlKey, string environment)
{
     BaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[urlKey];
     Environment = environment;
}
```

In this scenario, urlKey is the first value of the current TestAttribute, and environment is the second one. 
So, having this, I get the URL of my current server and I use it as my base url:

```
BaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[urlKey];
Environment = environment;
```

and "Environment" for logging purposes.

Comment: I don't really see what this has to do with running automation on several machines at once...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal this way allows running the same test several times, providing parameters you can take advantage of. If you set any of these parameters as URLs, then you will be able to run tests on several servers at once.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean you can run tests AGAINST several servers at once? I thought the question was asking how do you have your automation run ON several servers in parallel, not how to run it against various environments (ie QA, Dev, staging, and prod).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've clarified my question. I'm really looking for something like Selenium Grid to run these tests but I'd like to hear about better solutions if they exist.